# Core Data, iCloud & App was suspended with locked system files

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-data, icloud

I have an app that uses Core Data and iCloud: the transaction log is in user's ubiquitous container, the DB store file as well, and in a .nosync folder.

Usually there is no problem, but sometimes the app crashes with "App was suspended with locked system files". I noticed this is happening when the app is getting iCloud `NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification` and then the app updates its database.

What is the best practice for using iCloud & Core Data? I didn't see any recommendation in Apple doc like close the DB when entering background or remove the observer for iCloud notifications -- anyway, Apple claims that the iCloud infrastructure keeps updating the data even when the app is not running, so I guess I need to keep the observer.

*PS: I'm trying to add some info from the crash report, but StackOverflow doesn't want to accept it because of "wrong formatting".*

Comment: You don't have data protection enabled for your store files, do you?

Answer (score 1):

App crashing randomly is something that happens a lot when you try to use iCloud and Core Data.

The only way I could get it working was to mimic the implementation of this example : https://github.com/alekseyn/iCloudStoreManager

I used use the UbiquityStoreManager class provided (adapted for non-ARC in my case) and adapted all the iCloud-related and Core Data-related code in the AppDelegate/ViewControllers.

It was worth the re-factoring effort.